# NetSuite - SuiteScript 2.0: How to resolve 'Error: Load timeout for modules: N/redirect'?

Tags: timeout, runtime-error, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am using SuiteScript 2.0 in NetSuite and got an error when I open an existing invoice:

Error: Load timeout for modules: N/redirect

[image: 1]

I plan to do the followings:

1. Use a user event script to add a custom button on an invoice page to appear under 'view' mode. Upon clicking the button, a custom client-side script 'rs_cm_invoice_telema.js' is called and function 'onButtonClick' is executed.

   ```
   /**
    * @NApiVersion 2.0
    * @NScriptType UserEventScript
    */
   define(['N/ui/serverWidget'],
   /**
    * @param {serverWidget} serverWidget
    */
   function(serverWidget) {
       /**
        * Defines the function definition that is executed before record is loaded.
        * @param {Object} scriptContext
        * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
        * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type; use values from the context.UserEventType enum
        * @param {Form} scriptContext.form - Current form
        * @param {ServletRequest} scriptContext.request - HTTP request information sent from the browser for a client action only.
        * @since 2015.2
        */
       function beforeLoad(context) {

           var invoiceForm = context.form;

           // Set the module path to the custom client-side script
           invoiceForm.clientScriptModulePath = './rs_cm_invoice_telema.js';

           // Add a custom button to an invoice under 'view' mode
           invoiceForm.addButton({
               id           : 'custpage_export_invoice_to_telema_button',
               label        : 'Export to Telema',
               functionName : 'onButtonClick'
           });           

       }

       return {beforeLoad : beforeLoad}

   });
   ```
2. This custom client-side module calls another user event script using 'redirect' module. This is where the error occurs.

   ```
   /**
    * @NApiVersion 2.0
    */
   define(['N/log', 'N/redirect'],
   /**
    * @param {log} log
    * @param {redirect} redirect
    */
   function(log, redirect) {

       function callUserEventScript() {

           redirect.toSuitelet({
               scriptId     : '216',  // '<your-script-id>'
               deploymentId : '307',  // '<your-deployment-id>'
           });
       }

       return {onButtonClick: callUserEventScript}
   });
   ```
3. The user event script that the custom module above is supposed to call doesn't have 'N'/redirect' module. The codes there are quite long, so I won't include them here unless it is needed.

I use Microsoft Edge and Edge didn't have a problem with runtime error from loading 'N/redirect' module at the beginning. I started facing this issue after a while.

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need additional information. Thank you.

I have tried the followings:

- Cleared cache/cookies on Microsoft Edge
- Tried on Google Chrome

I was expecting 'N/redirect' to load and call a user event script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that 'N/redirect' module is for a server-side script. I was using it in the client-side script, hence the error.

Solution from SuiteAnswers can be found here https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12239/loc/en_US

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).